# How to link to a specific section of a Bootstrap modal

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I have a simple website made with react, I am trying to add some links at the top of a Boostrap modal, so that when clicked, it takes you to a specific section of the modal.

for example a link looks like this,

```
<h4><a href="#iob" id="PCBoneSection">Infected Olecrenon Bursitis</a></h4>
```

and the `div` I want it to take us to looks like this,

```
<div className="text-left border border-info rounded" id="iob">
//some code
</div>
```

Before opening the Bootstrap modal, we are on this page link. `www.page.com/primary/guide` Then we click an img which then opens the modal.

If I try it with the above code, the modal disappears and the screen fades, and my url now says
`www.page.com/primary/guide/#iob`

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had upadted my id in the code but forgot to change it in my question. I have edited the original question. The id for the div is `iob` and the href is `#iob`

Comment: I think the native link inside the modal body won't work unless you specifically bind the click event.